# Refactor JavaScript nested if-else

Tags: javascript, beginner, dom

I'm really new to code optimization and JS. I would like to ask for help on optimizing my code. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
if(entity_param_connections_products == "PL") {
      if(pl_flex_l1_label === ""){
        document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l1-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_l1_label;
      }
      
      if(pl_flex_n1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n1-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_n1_label;
      }
      
      if(pl_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_t1_label;
      }
      
      if(pl_flex_l2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l2-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_l2_label;
      }
      
      if(pl_flex_n2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n2-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_n2_label;
      }
      
      if(pl_flex_t2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t2-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_t2_label;
      }
  }else if(entity_param_connections_products == "CC"){
      if(cc_flex_l1_label === ""){
        document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l1-label').innerHTML = cc_flex_l1_label;
      }
      
      if(cc_flex_n1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n1-label').innerHTML = cc_flex_n1_label;
      }
      
      if(cc_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = cc_flex_t1_label;
      }
      
      if(cc_flex_l2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l2-label').innerHTML = cc_flex_l2_label;
      }
      
      if(cc_flex_n2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n2-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_n2_label;
      }
      
      if(cc_flex_t2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t2-label').innerHTML = cc_flex_t2_label;
      }
  }else if(entity_param_connections_products == "II"){
      if(ii_flex_l1_label === ""){
        document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l1-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_l1_label;
      }
      
      if(ii_flex_n1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n1-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_n1_label;
      }
      
      if(ii_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_t1_label;
      }
      
      if(ii_flex_l2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l2-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_l2_label;
      }
      
      if(ii_flex_n2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n2-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_n2_label;
      }
      
      if(ii_flex_t2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t2-label').innerHTML = ii_flex_t2_label;
      }
  }else if(entity_param_connections_products == "EI"){
     if(ei_flex_l1_label === ""){
        document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l1-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_l1_label;
      }
      
      if(ei_flex_n1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n1-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_n1_label;
      }
      
      if(ei_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_t1_label;
      }
      
      if(ei_flex_l2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l2-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_l2_label;
      }
      
      if(ei_flex_n2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n2-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_n2_label;
      }
      
      if(ei_flex_t2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t2-label').innerHTML = ei_flex_t2_label;
      }
  }else if(entity_param_connections_products == "OV"){
      if(ov_flex_l1_label === ""){
        document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l1-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_l1_label;
      }
      
      if(ov_flex_n1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n1-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_n1_label;
      }
      
      if(ov_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_t1_label;
      }
      
      if(ov_flex_l2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_l2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_l2-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_l2_label;
      }
      
      if(ov_flex_n2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_n2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_n2-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_n2_label;
      }
      
      if(ov_flex_t2_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t2").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t2-label').innerHTML = ov_flex_t2_label;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `I'm really new to code optimization` Better develop a useful judgement of *when* to pursue code improvements first.

Comment: (I'm afraid this *is* a beginner's real code.)

Comment: We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already suggested, you can abstract common logic to a function:

```js
const updateElement = function(idPrefix, value) {
  if (value === "") {
    document.getElementById(idPrefix).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + "-label").innerHTML = value;
  }
}
updateElement("credit_app-flex_t1", pl_flex_t1_label);
```

Still, this would lead to duplicated code:

```js
if(entity_param_connections_products === "PL") {
  updateElement("credit_app-flex_t1", pl_flex_t1_label);
  ...
} else if(entity_param_connections_products == "CC") {
  updateElement("credit_app-flex_t1", cc_flex_t1_label);
  ...
}
...
```

To remove this duplicated code, you could use an object:

```js
const configs = {
  PL: {
    l1: pl_flex_l1_label,
    n2: pl_flex_n2_label,
    ...
  },
  CC: {
    l1: cc_flex_l1_label,
    ...
  },
  ...
};
const config = configs[entity_param_connections_products];
for(const [id, value] of Object.entries(config)) {
  updateElement("credit_app-flex_" + id, value);
}
```

Comment: I would also take a good look at the `XX_flex_YY_label` variables and see if those can be restructured into a `flex_label.XX.YY` structure

Comment: @Dancrumb that would be a great idea, as that could make the code even simpler (in my suggestion it would remove the `configs` object). And we would avoid the idea of accesing the `window` object with formated variables names (as suggested by @Blindman67)

Answer (score 2):

### D.R.Y.ing code

To remove repeated code

### Common unchanging code

Locate the common parts of the repetitive code and build functions that contains the repeated code, we replace the changing part by passing arguments to function with the values that are changing.

### Unique code

Next we locate changing parts of the code. We must build names and get values based on the unique values we pass to the functions created in the step above.

In your case

- Label text has the name eg `pl_flex_l1_label` that consist of two changing parts that is highlighted with *"#"* `#1_flex_#2_label`

  - *"#1"* is the same as the value of `entity_param_connections_products` forced to lowercase
  - *"#2"* is one of 6 values `"l1"`, `"n1"`, `"t1"`, `"l2"`, `"n2"` and, `"t2"` that are the same for each of the values for *"#1"*. We can build an array to hold these values.

    ```
    const labelTypes = "l1,n1,t1,l2,n2,t2".split(",");
    ```
- There are two elements per label, one is contains that label and the second holds the text. They are identified by id `"credit_app-flex_#2"` and `"credit_app-flex_#2-label"`. Again *"#2"* is one of six values common to all values of *"#1"*

  The next function `buildLabel` gets a label value from the global object `window` and the label element id returning it as an array. `prod` is the value `entity_param_connections_products` and type is one of the six label types.

  For each label type we call buildLabel and put ir in an array. We do this in the function `getProductLabels` that returns an array of arrays

  ```
  const buildLabel = (prod, type) => [
      window[[prod.toLowerCase(), "flex", type, "label"].join("_")], 
      "credit_app-flex_" + type
  ];  
  const getProductLabels = productCon => labelTypes.map(type => buildLabel(productCon, type));
  ```
- Now we have an array that contains all the unique values associated with a `entity_param_connections_products` value. The last thing we do is hide or display the associated label for each of the items in the array create by `getProductLabels`

  The function `updateLabel` takes an array containing the label value and the label id and hides or displays the label depending on the label value. This is called once per label type.

  ```
  const updateLabel = ([label, productId]) => {
        const el = document.getElementById(productId + (label ? "-label" : ""));
        label ? el.textContent = label : el.style.display = "none";
  }
  ```

### Rewrite

The only part that changes at the top level is the value of `entity_param_connections_products` which we can use to start the chain of calls of the functions we defined above.

We put all the code together in a function that encapsulate all the parts and keeps them safely out of the global scope.

```
function updateLabels(productName) {
    const labelTypes = "l1,n1,t1,l2,n2,t2".split(",");
    const buildLabel = (prod, type) => [
        window[[prod.toLowerCase(), "flex", type, "label"].join("_")], 
        "credit_app-flex_" + type
    ];
    const getProductLabels = productCon => labelTypes.map(type => buildLabel(productCon, type));
    const updateLabel = ([label, productId]) => {
        const el = document.getElementById(productId + (label ? "-label" : ""));
        label ? el.textContent = label : el.style.display = "none";
    }
    getProductLabels(productName).forEach(updateLabel);
}
```

With just the above function in place we can now replace all your code with

```
updateLabels(entity_param_connections_products);
```

### DRY V original

We have taken 180 lines of repetitive code and put it into 14 lines. If names or ids change and the common parts remain the same it is easy to change a value without needing to change each unique value in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions and ternary operator logic here to reduce a lot of line and to make it more clear.

For example

```js
if(pl_flex_t1_label === ""){
          document.getElementById("credit_app-flex_t1").style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('credit_app-flex_t1-label').innerHTML = pl_flex_t1_label;
      }
```

can be simplified into

```js
var setStyleDisplayToNon = function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
};

var setInnerHTML = function(id, value) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
};

pl_flex_t1_label === "" ? setStyleDisplayToNon("credit_app-flex_t1") : setInnerHTML("credit_app-flex_t1-label", pl_flex_t1_label);
```

With functions `setStyleDisplayToNon` and `setInnerHTML` defined only once, all your code can simply call those functions.

Comment: This will still leave you with 30 lines of nearly identical code.